# Angular8: How to filter unique record

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

- **Want to Implement:**
  Want to populate unique element in drop down.
- Problem Description :

Getting record as per query some value hold duplicate record But I am unable to display unique value in dropdowm.

- Trying To Implement :

Searching a way to DISPLAY only the unique record.

- Current Implementation:

**

- Repository Code:

**

```
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<ccCategory,Integer>
{

    public static final String FIND_CATEGORYNAME = "SELECT DISTINCT * from xxCategory where active='1'";

    @Query(value = FIND_CATEGORYNAME, nativeQuery = true)

    List<xxCategory > getCategoryName();
}
```

**-

- Controller :

**

```
@GetMapping("/getAllCategory")
        public List<xxCategory> getAllCategory() {
        List<ccCategory> cCategory = categoryRepository.getCategoryName();
        return cCategory;
    }
```

**- Angular Side :**

```
<label class="control-label">Category: </label>
                <select  [(ngModel)]="listAllCategory" name="enquirycategory" class="form-control" required>


                    <option *ngFor="let enquirycategory of listAllCategory" [value]="enquirycategory.ID">
                      {{enquirycategory.categoryName}}
                  </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter the result before rendering into DOM.

Here is how you can filter :

```
this.uniqueCatogaries = this.categories.filter((item, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.id === item.id
  ))
```

then in `component.html`  `*ngFor` on `uniqueCatogaries` array :

```
<select  [(ngModel)]="listAllCategory" name="enquirycategory"     class="form-control" required>
<option *ngFor="let enquirycategory of uniqueCatogaries" [value]="enquirycategory.ID">
{{enquirycategory.name}}
</option>
</select>
```

here is working example  :  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbaupf)

Comment: My all values is coming in DROPDOWN but I want to select the unique value ... like stuff is coming two times it  should be come only one time. My API returning diefferntcategoryName with the same id. So I want to display unique record only.

Comment: @Jaiswal after receiving the values , you need to apply above logic in the subscribe of the api call.